# Snake Game in Java

Tags: java, beginner, swing, snake-game

I am a self-taught coder, and have been learning Java for the last 2 months.

I have recently created a snake game in Java with the help of an online tutorial. I have rearranged the program into separate classes & methods. I am skeptical on how good of a programmer I am, and I code messy.

I don't really want help on how to make the game better in visuals, levels, or anything like that. I am asking those who are more advanced programmers to help me with implementing programming techniques, better organization, how to comment better, etc. Pretty much anything that will help me become a better programmer.

Also, I have commented a few things out of pure guess, so if it appears as if I have gotten something wrong, please correct me!

Also, any extra tips for my future projects would be much appreciated!

Node

```
public class Node {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Node(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Snake

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Snake {

    private LinkedList<Node> body = new LinkedList<Node>();

    public boolean isEatFood(Node food) {
        Node head = body.getFirst();
        return Math.abs(head.getX() - food.getX()) + Math.abs(head.getY() - food.getY()) == 0;
    }

    public Node move(Direction direction) {
        Node node = null;
        int headX = this.body.getFirst().getX();
        int headY = this.body.getFirst().getY();
        switch(direction) {
            case UP :
                node = new Node(headX, headY - 1);
                break;
            case RIGHT :
                node = new Node(headX + 1, headY);
                break;
            case DOWN :
                node = new Node(headX, headY + 1);
                break;
            case LEFT :
                node = new Node(headX - 1, headY);
                break;
        }
        this.body.addFirst(node);
        return body.removeLast();
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return body.getFirst();
    }

    public Node addTail(Node area) {
        this.body.addLast(area);
        return area;
    }

    public LinkedList<Node> getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Grid

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Grid {

    private boolean isCovered[][];
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private int scores = 0;

    private Snake snake;
    private Node food;

    private Direction snakeDirection = Direction.LEFT;         // initial direction is LEFT 
    public boolean isDirectionChanged = false;

    public Grid(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        isCovered = new boolean[width][height];

        initSnake();
        createFood();
    }
    private Snake initSnake() {                                 // initial Snake has 3 Node
        snake = new Snake();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            snake.addTail(new Node(i + width / 2, height / 2));
            isCovered[i + width / 2][height / 2] = true;
        }
        return snake;
    }

    public Node createFood() {
        int x,y;
        do {
            x = new Random( ).nextInt(width);
            y = new Random( ).nextInt(height);
        } while (isCovered[x][y] == true);
        food = new Node(x, y);
        return food;
    }

    public boolean nextRound() {                                     //follow the direction and move one step
        if (isMoveValid(snakeDirection)) {
            Node move = snake.move(snakeDirection);
            if (snake.isEatFood(food)) {                             //if ate food, add the Node moved at tail
                snake.addTail(move);
                createFood();
                System.out.println(++scores);
            } else isCovered[move.getX()][move.getY()] = false;
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
    private boolean isMoveValid(Direction direction) {
        int headX = snake.getHead().getX();
        int headY = snake.getHead().getY();
        switch(direction) {
            case UP :
                headY--;
                break;
            case RIGHT :
                headX++;
                break;
            case DOWN :
                headY++;
                break;
            case LEFT :
                headX--;
                break;
        }
        if (headX < 0 || headX >= width || headY < 0 || headY >= height) return false;
        if (isCovered[headX][headY] == true) return false;
        isCovered[headX][headY] = true;
        return true;
    }

    public void changeDirection(Direction newDirection) {
        if (snakeDirection.compatibleWith(newDirection)) {
            snakeDirection = newDirection;
            isDirectionChanged = true;
        }
    }

    public Snake getSnake() { return snake; }
    public Node getFood() { return food; }
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
    public int getScore() { return scores; }

}
```

GameController

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameController implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    private final Grid grid;
    private final GameView gameView;

    private boolean running;

    public GameController(Grid grid, GameView gameView) {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.gameView = gameView;
        this.running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Math.max(50, 200 - grid.getScore() / 5 * 30));                     //DEFAULT_MOVE_INTERVAL
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            grid.isDirectionChanged = false;
            if (grid.nextRound() == true) {
                gameView.draw();
            } else {
                System.out.print("Congraduations! Your scores: " + grid.getScore());
                gameView.showGameOverMessage();
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (grid.isDirectionChanged == false) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP :
                    grid.changeDirection(Direction.UP);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                    grid.changeDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN :
                    grid.changeDirection(Direction.DOWN);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT :
                    grid.changeDirection(Direction.LEFT);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE :
                    break;
            }
        }
        // repaint the canvas
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

SnakeApp

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SnakeApp implements Runnable {

    private final int DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH = 30;
    private final int DEFAULT_GRID_HEIGHT = 30;
    private GameView gameView;
    private GameController gameController;

    public void run() {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Snake Game");               //creat game window

        Container contentPane = window.getContentPane();
        // use Grid initialize the gamaView
        Grid grid = new Grid(DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH, DEFAULT_GRID_HEIGHT);
        gameView = new GameView(grid);
        gameView.init();

        // set JPanel's size
        gameView.getCanvas().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH * gameView.DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE, 
            DEFAULT_GRID_HEIGHT * gameView.DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE));
        // add JPanel to windows
        contentPane.add(gameView.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // draw grid and snake
        window.pack();
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

        gameController = new GameController(grid, gameView);
        window.addKeyListener(gameController);

        // start the thread
        new Thread(gameController).start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SnakeApp snakeApp = new SnakeApp();
        //snakeApp.run();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SnakeApp());
    }
}
```

GameView

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameView {
    //use Graphics API draw pics
    private JPanel canvas;
    private final Grid grid;
    public final int DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE = 15;

    public GameView(Grid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public void init() {
        canvas = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
                drawGridBackground(graphics);
                drawSnake(graphics, grid.getSnake());
                drawFood(graphics, grid.getFood());
            }
        };
    }

    public void draw() {
        canvas.repaint();
    }

    public JPanel getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public void drawSnake(Graphics graphics, Snake snake) {
        for (Node node : snake.getBody()) {
            drawSquare(graphics, node, Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
    public void drawFood(Graphics graphics, Node squareArea) {
        drawCircle(graphics, squareArea, Color.RED);
    }
    public void drawGridBackground(Graphics graphics) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.getHeight(); j++) {
                drawSquare(graphics, new Node(i, j), new Color(127, 127, 127, 255));
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawSquare(Graphics graphics, Node squareArea, Color color) {
        graphics.setColor(color);
        int size = DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE;                                 
        graphics.fillRect(squareArea.getX() * size, squareArea.getY() * size, size - 1, size - 1);
    }
    private void drawCircle(Graphics graphics, Node squareArea, Color color) {
        graphics.setColor(color);
        int size = DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE;
        graphics.fillOval(squareArea.getX() * size-1, squareArea.getY() * size-1, size, size);
    }

    public void showGameOverMessage() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!", "GameOver", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you forget to add class `Direction`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a great achievement for a self-taught programmer of only a few months.  Pat yourself on the back!  Good formatting, good separation of concerns, mostly good variable names, methods are short and do one thing.

You are missing the Direction.java file.  I created one to see if the program would run.  It does and it's fun!

```
public enum Direction {
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN;

    public boolean compatibleWith(Direction newDirection) {
        if (this.equals(LEFT) || this.equals(RIGHT)) {
            return UP.equals(newDirection) || DOWN.equals(newDirection); 
        } else {
            return LEFT.equals(newDirection) || RIGHT.equals(newDirection);
        }
    }
}
```

### Ways to Improve

- Not enough comments.  All public methods should be commented unless they are truly trivial, like getters and setters.  Don't put comment in the right margin.
- With a project this size, you should have a package name.  Having all the files in one package would be fine, but better would be to have model, controller view.  Your classes are already set up this way.
- I would rename Grid.java to GameGrid or SnakeGrid.  "Grid" is a little too generic for my taste.  (Nitpick).

#### SnakeApp.java

These lines:

```
private final int DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH = 30;
private final int DEFAULT_GRID_HEIGHT = 30;
```

...should be static too if they're going to be constants are the variable names imply.

#### Node.java

I would make this class final.  Good job making it immutable.

#### Grid.java

This is one of only a few places when your formatting is poor:

```
public boolean nextRound() {                                     //follow the direction and move one step
    if (isMoveValid(snakeDirection)) {
        Node move = snake.move(snakeDirection);
        if (snake.isEatFood(food)) {                             //if ate food, add the Node moved at tail
            snake.addTail(move);
            createFood();
            System.out.println(++scores);
        } else isCovered[move.getX()][move.getY()] = false;
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Never put the else clause on the same on the same line as `else`.  Put it in braces.  If fact, I put braces around *all* the clauses in an `if` statement.  It's clearer and less likely to cause bugs when being maintained.

#### Snake.java

I this statement:

```
private LinkedList<Node> body = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

...you don't need to repeat the generic type on the right-hand side.  This will do:

```
private LinkedList<Node> body = new LinkedList<>();
```

There's no reason to use `this` with fields unless you're disambiguating it from a parameter.

In the method move(), your `switch` statement needs a default case where you set `node` to null.  Then you don't have to initialize `node` to null in the declaration.

#### GameController

Don't write:

```
if (grid.nextRound() == true) {
```

...just write

```
if (grid.nextRound()) {
```

Now you can see the "nextRound" may not be the best name for that method.

I think the boolean `running` can be a local variable instead of a field.